# Numpy: efficient way to find first smallest value per row appearing in a later column than the match of previous row

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of dimension ~(20, 150) with entries between `i` and `i+1` where `i` is the column index. I have a mask that I apply on this array and then I want to find the index/value of the minimum of remaining entries per row, which is smaller than the result for the previous row.

For example with the following smaller array (replaced the masked values by `nan`)

```
[[nan, 1.2, 2.5, nan, nan,   6],
 [ 0., nan, 2.4, 3.1, nan, nan],
 [nan, 1.1, 2.3, nan, nan, 5.5]]
```

I would expect

```
[1.2, 2.4, 5.5]
```

Also, if a row has no match, then I would expect `nan` for it and all the following rows.

I have a solution using a for loop over each row using `np.nanmin` but I would like to know if there would be a way more efficient way to do it. Here is my example.

```
a = np.array([[nan, 1.2, 2.5, nan, nan,   6],
              [ 0., nan, 2.4, 3.1, nan, nan],
              [nan, 1.1, 2.3, nan, nan, 5.5]])
condition = ~np.isnan(a)
prev = [0]
res = []
for i, (row, cond) in enumerate(zip(a, condition)):
    prev = np.nanmin(row, initial=np.nan, where=cond & (row>=prev), keepdims=True)
    res.append(prev)
```

which yields

```
[array([1.2]), array([2.4]), array([5.5])]
```

In this case I don't really need the condition array but it's too represent how it's going to be in my real application where the condition is a little bit more tricky and uses another array.

Comment: Iterative processes aren't usually sped up by `numpy`, but there may be a `numba`  solution.

Comment: This is actually a step in a program simulating some 2D movement over time for which the use of numpy is very beneficial. I would like to improve the performance of this step.
In practice, the array I'm using also has an additional dimension, and is usually of size ~(100, 20, 150)

Comment: Would you give the actual data shape you want to use with more specific description

Comment: @user2586955 I have ~100 samples, for each samples I have ~20 locations, for each location I have 150 timestamps (all in 1 second intervals). 

The timestamp is "at what time was I the closest to location `k` and I removed the timestamps where I'm too far away from the location.

I want to know when I reached each location (for each sample). Knowing that each location has to be reached in order.